# How to get a unique id for database child in firebase website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have initialized firebase and want to write into database . I want unique code for every child but i am not able to do that i tried many things but i can't please help me to do this ..............
codes are below tell me where i am wrong

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.1.3/firebase.js"></script>
```

```
<script>
var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('user');
       $('#tex').click(function(){
              rootRef.set({
              emailinfo:$('#emailinfo').val()
       });
});
</script>
```

Comment: plzzz answer fast

Comment: for more information regarding error cheak my website page where i used that code [www.arvindsingh.dx.am/issue.html]

Comment: Did you try the Firebase Documentation [Reading and Writing Lists: Push](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#reading_and_writing_lists)? *The push() method generates a unique key every time a new child is added*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`push()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.Reference#push) method (which "generates a new child location using a unique key and returns its Reference"), as follows:

```
<script>
       var rootRef = firebase.database().ref().child('user');
       var newNodeRef = rootRef.push();

       $('#tex').click(function(){
            newNodeRef.set({
              emailinfo:$('#emailinfo').val()
            });
       });
</script>
```